# Nowadays, whom is Birkat Haminim directed at?

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, birchat-haminim

Today I saw this question: [History of Birkas haMinim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7678/history-of-birkas-haminim), which got me thinking: Nowadays, that we don't have Tzdokim or little Judaic Temple-cults like the Essenes, whom is the Birkat Haminim directed at? Just Christians? Or other religions? If the latter, then: all other religions or just some of them? And might it also be directed at some Jews (Chalilah?) as it was in the beginning? What about Kara'im and Shomronim?

Comment: Why are you so sure there are evil people to direct it at nowadays, but so hesitant to think any are Jews?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/103009/2020/1/15/0-20

Comment: Look at the end of Beer HaGoleh by the Maharal. The last piece is on this blessing.

Comment: @Double AA I originally planned to include a few specific communities in Judaism in the question but then thought that maybe it would be rude to other users of the site. That's why I also added a question mark to the word chalilah. It may not be chalilah...also, the concept of "tinok shnishba" has evolved to my knowledge. Can we really just point fingers of minut and apikorsut at everyone?